# Getting a jumbled data or wrong data while processing native query in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, join, nativequery

i am writing a native query in jpa repository with left join and getting a jumbled output and adding more columns to the query is generating a error of conversion from java.object to my model class. Moreover when i try to return all from the output of join it is giving as duplication of id use alias

i have tried making different class and interface to store the query result but not happening

this is the repository

```
@Repository

public interface GroupRepository extends JpaRepository<Groups, Long> {

@Query (value="SELECT gad.id ,gha.id as groupattributeid , gad.group_id ,gad.value , gad.attribute_id, gha.hierarchy_id  FROM group_attr_data gad JOIN group_hierarchy_attributes gha ON  gad.attribute_id = gha.id where gad.group_id = ?1",nativeQuery = true)

 Collection<GroupAttData> viewGroupAttData(Long group_id);

 }
```

this is my controller

```
    public class GroupController {

    @Autowired
GroupRepository groupRepository;
@RequestMapping(value="/view-group-attr-data", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json" , produces = "application/json")

public Collection<GroupAttData> ViewGroupAttData(@RequestBody GroupAttrData request) throws ResourceNotFoundException{

    if(groupRepository.viewGroupAttData(request.getGroup_id()).isEmpty()) {

        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("groups not found " );

    }   else {

        return (List<GroupAttData>) groupRepository.viewGroupAttData(request.getGroup_id());

    }

}
}
```

this is my model interface of GroupAttData

```
 public interface GroupAttData {

public Long getid();
public Long getgroup_id() ;
public Long getattribute_id();
public String getvalue();
public Long getgroupattributeid();
public Long gethierarchy_id();

}
```

Actual result should be

```
 SELECT gad.id ,gha.id as groupattributeid , gad.group_id ,gad.value ,gad.attribute_id, gha.hierarchy_id FROM group_attr_data gad JOIN group_hierarchy_attributes gha ON  gad.attribute_id = gha.id where gad.group_id = 1;

 # id, groupattributeid, group_id, value, attribute_id, hierarchy_id
  '299'       '7'            '1'     '33'      '7',        '1'
```

the coming result is

```
 [
  {
    "hierarchy_id": 33,
    "groupattributeid": 1,
    "id": 7,
    "value": "1",
    "group_id": 7,
    "attribute_id": 299
  }
 ]
```

As in For hierarchy_id it should be 1 where as the coming output data is 33 AND for value it should be coming 33 where as the result data is 1 in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using camelCase nomenclature

```
public interface GroupAttData {

  Long getId();
  Long getGroupId() ;
  Long getAttributeId();
  String getValue();
  Long getGroupattributeid();
  Long getHierarchyId();

}
```

Comment: i have done that before but it is giving me a type conversion error

Comment: mmm, try using the previous way, but adding the value annotation @Value("#{target.groupattributeid }") Long getattribute_id();

Comment: getting a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException error